# Different PID for the same process

Tags: linux, process

I am just trying to understand more about the PID column when running the ps command.
If I have two terminal windows open, in the first one I run the following command

```
firefox &
```

Then run the `ps` command in BOTH and get the following output from the first window

```
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
  16814 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
  16822 pts/1    00:00:04 MainThread
  16881 pts/1    00:00:02 Privileged Cont
  16938 pts/1    00:00:00 WebExtensions
  17026 pts/1    00:00:00 Web Content
  17081 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

And the following in the second

```
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
  16794 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
  17082 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

In both outputs we see the shell process. Why do they not have the same PID, even if it has the same process name.

Comment: Simple: each terminal has its own bash process. What you see is what you got.

Comment: If you do `man ps`, you will see the fragment: "By default, ps selects all processes with the same effective user ID (euid=EUID) as the current user and associated with the same terminal as the invoker".

Comment: Illustrative and interesting to study may be to do `ps a` or better yet: `ps af`.